# grep from a list to produce multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with unique values in it as follows

```
red
green
blue
yellow
```

I have another dataframe with colours and other columns as follows

```
red        1        4
green      2        4
blue       2        5
yellow     1        7
red        54      35
green      25      54
blue       33      66
yellow     63      63
blue       22      99
yellow     80      25
red        26      33
green      16      17
```

I need to create dataframes which are the result of grepping out the rows with each colour (with the dataframe named by colour eg:

```
dfred
 red        1        4
 red        54      35
 red        26      33
dfyellow
 yellow     1        7
 yellow     63      63
 yellow     80      25

dfblue
 blue       2        5
 blue       33      66
 blue       22      99

dfgreen
 green      2        4
 green      25      54
 green      16      17
```

I could do this one by one by think there's an easier way. Can this be done in a function?

I really don't know how to substitute each grep phrase into a function that would output such a named dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `split` to create a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
lst <- split(df2, as.character(df2$col1))
names(lst) <- paste0('df', names(lst))
```

and then with `list2env` create the individual objects in the global environment (not recommended though)

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
dfred
#   col1 col2 col3
#1   red    1    4
#5   red   54   35
#11  red   26   33
```

Comment: Tick for the use of split and renaming the result. Not so sure about the creation of individual object being needed in my case but thanks